Create reactive named lists
I'm creating a shiny app where I would like to allow the user to give the value in a list a reactive name. In the minimal example below I would like to have the dropdown menu value ("example1") be assigned as the name of the value in the list. I was thinking of using glue ({{}}) to make it interactive like this:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Make reactive a named list"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("choices",
                        "Make a choice",
                        c("example1", "example2", "example3"))
        ),

        mainPanel(
           textOutput("text")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    list("{{input$choices}}" = TRUE)
  })

    output$text <- renderPrint({
        data()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Current output:

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. As we can see from the output the reactive input$choices value is not assigned to the list. So my expected output would be: $example2 [1] TRUE. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to assign a reactive value to a list like this?

Does this answer your question? Creating a named list from two vectors (names, values) - Hi Quinten, Shiny is a bit of a red herring here, the question is just about named lists really.

You can use setNames or names:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Make reactive a named list"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "choices",
        "Make a choice",
        c("example1", "example2", "example3")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("text")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({
    setNames(list(TRUE), input$choices)
  })

  output$text <- renderPrint({
    data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8918


